# Should .csv entry end with delimiter?

Tags: csv

Should one end each entry with a delimiter (in this case ','):

```
axis1,axis2,axis3,
    1,    2,    3,
    2,    3,    4,
```

or not:

```
axis1,axis2,axis3
    1,    2,    3
    2,    3,    4
```

in a .csv or is this just different dialects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not so [according to RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) where a csv record (line) is defined as

```
record = field *(COMMA field)
```

Which doesn't mean you'll never encounter the form with a trailing comma, as csv is notorious for its variations and deviations, and sometimes sloppy implementations.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you. Normally I would expect **not**. Why ? Because when you perform a `split()` (or similar) operation on

```
A,B,C,D
```

I would expect to end up with 4 elements (A-D). If I did the same on:

```
A,B,C,D,
```

I would normally expect most implementations/languages to give me a final element of zero length, due to the final comma. You then have to handle this (ignore it, throw it away etc.).

Answer (score 1):

No, there should be no column delimiter at the end of the line. If there is, this means there is another empty column.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the way to go. No delimiter at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is best, otherwise your parsing will assume there is a blank record at end of every row.  Delimiter should only be between records to "delimit" them.